# Failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, vmware-workstation

I have got some problem when I installed Docker with Window Server.
The environment list:

> 1  Windows 10 (Physical Machine)
>   2.VMware® Workstation Player (12~ above) [URL](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/14_0)
>   3.Windows Server 2016 at the VM
>   4.Docker CE for Windows(stable) [URL](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows)

the problem picture and content
[image]

```
Unable to start: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: 'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start.

Failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID BBD755F7-05B6-4933-B1E0-F8ACA3D2467B)     

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID BBD755F7-05B6-4933-B1E0-F8ACA3D2467B).
at Start-MobyLinuxVM, <No file>: line 315
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 410
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 256
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 130
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 47
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 145
```

How can I fix this problem issue,Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to run docker for windows inside a virtual machine?

Comment: Hi @Mathias yes at the Windows

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hi all I have found the answer to deal with this problem hopefully this content can help someone who has the same issue.
1. to setup VM at Virtual Machine Settings (like as following picture)
[image]

[image]

2. to setup the Hyper-V in the Windows Server 2016 (like as following picture)
   [image]

Mandarin reference [URL](https://skychang.github.io/2017/01/06/Docker-Docker_for_Windows_10_First/)

Comment: Where can I find those settings in the first screenshot?

Comment: @CharlesMorin added another picture, helpfully it can help you

Answer (score 39):

Here is a **solution** if you are getting this error on an **Azure Windows 10 VM** where you have installed Docker and this is already [Nested Virtualization capable VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization#create-a-nesting-capable-azure-vm) in other words your Azure VM must be [`V3` sized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/acu) as minimum ([DV3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv3-dsv3-series) or [EV3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/ev3-esv3-series)):

> - Ensure Windows Hyper-V featutes are enabled by running PowerShell cmdlet:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All -Verbose`

> - Ensure Windows Containers feature is enabled by running PowerShell cmdlet:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers -All -Verbose`

> - Ensure Hypervisor is set to auto start in the Boot Configuration Database (BCD) by running in **elevated command prompt** the command:

`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto`

After running all of the above and you restart the Azure VM, Docker should be starting normally.

> In addition to the Answer above the PowerShell cmdlet to set the Virtual Machine Setting is:

`Set-VMProcessor -VMName <Enter-VM-Name> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true -Verbose`

> Still have an issue and haven't rebooted yet?! - just restart the windows services by running the following:

```
net stop vmms 
net start vmms
```

Comment: Docker stopped working after some windows update... Thx to your solution it's up and running again :)

Comment: I exactly followed these steps in a Win 10 Azure VM but docker still shows the same error. Investigating...

Comment: It looks like Docker only works on certain types of Azure VMs, like D*_v3 and E*_v3. It doesn't work on D*_v2 for example. After resizing my VM to D*_v3 docker started successfully.

Comment: Yes, indeed - rule number one your VM must support "Nested virtualization" - check the [azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization); This answer provides solution once the VM already has Nested virtualisation available.

Comment: as you explained that Standard D2s v3 (2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory)  is solved the problem.

Answer (score 32):

In case this helps anyone else getting this issue, I found that running these commands from an admin command prompt fixed my Hyper-V issue:

```
net stop vmms 
net start vmms
```

I then was able to start my docker container without issue.

Comment: I am running Windows 10 Pro in an azure VM and It worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Enabling Hyper-V feature is **not enough in Azure VM**. You have to have "Nested virtualization" enabled, so according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization) you should choose `v3` sized VM:

> all v3 virtual machines support nested virtualization

After resizing, VM will be restarted and DockerVM in Hyper-V will run.

Comment: Thanks man, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

This is a nested virtualization issue to fix it running VMWare 6.5 and Windows 10 guest turn off the VM and select the option to Expose hardware assisted virtualization to the guest OS.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Open up a PowerShell or CMD session as Administrator.
2. Type the following command:

   ```
   Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
   ```

Comment: Just found it myself that it needs to be run into VM and not on host.

Comment: This [answer has already been added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50099965/542251)

Answer (score 2):

I went to docker settings and in `General` section selected to install the `other version` (bottom of the page as link). I initially installed the `stable`, changed for `beta` / edge.

That worked without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Actualy the reason is you have not enabled ExposeVirtualizationExtensions on host.
Shut down nested VM.
Run  PS command on host:

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName "NESTED VM NAME" -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

And then start nested VM (with docker in it) again.

Answer (score 1):

I oddly got this error when attempting to run Docker Desktop on a windows virtual machine and fixed by switching to windows containers on the Docker context menu(accessed by right-clicking on the docker icon on the tray):[image]

Answer (score 0):

**VMWare**

For VMWare, to enable hardware virtualization on the Guest OS, you do it from the VMWare web client. Note that the traditional desktop client does not have the option to enable hardware virtualization on Guest OS. Remember to shut down guest OS first else the option will be disabled.

[image]

[image]

Also see: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4470#issuecomment-519511295

**Windows Hypervisor**

If your doing virtualization using Windows Hypervisor and not something like VM Ware, in that case run below command from host machine:

```
Set-VMProcessor MyVM2 -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

See: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4470#issuecomment-579529145