# Unable to start: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop

Tags: linux, windows, docker, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have installed the Docker for Windows in my windows 10 machine. When I'm trying to "switch to linux container" from "windows container", I'm getting an error.

[image]

> Unable to start: The running command stopped because the preference
>   variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop:
>   'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start.
>
> Failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the
>   Hyper-V components is not running.
>
> 'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID
>   2E563FF9-8F28-49F9-A0D1-4E64BCCC3438)
>
> The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual
>   machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not
>   running (Virtual machine ID 2E563FF9-8F28-49F9-A0D1-4E64BCCC3438). at
>   Start-MobyLinuxVM, : line 296 at , :
>   line 412    at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action,
>   Object[] parameters) in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:line
>   36    at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.b__0() in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line
>   305    at Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:line 59

I have followed the similar question on SO ([Failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255871/failed-to-start-the-virtual-machine-mobylinuxvm-because-one-of-the-hyper-v-com)) but the solutions which posted in the question didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7):

Follow these steps:

1. Uncheck Hyper-V option by going to *Turn Windows Feature On or Off*
2. Restart the Windows machine (let docker complain about Hyper-V not available)
3. Enable Hyper-V again
4. Restart the machine (let docker start again).

Now it should be working.

Comment: This did not work for me.  So, unfortunately, not a 100% solution :~(

Comment: It leads to a different type of error in my case: 'Unable to destroy - The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Invalid class' which I was able to fix by following WMI repository fix stated at 
https://superuser.com/questions/1152280/get-net-powershell-cmdlets-failing-with-invalid-class

Comment: Thanks, it works great, I think there was some error when Windows updating.