# How to run docker on windows 10?

Tags: docker

I just installed Docker on Windows 10.
When I run Docker **as an administrator** I get the following error:

```
Unable to create: The running command stopped because the preference 
variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Hyper-V 
encountered an error trying to access an object on computer 'WP2975' because 
the object was not found. The object might have been deleted. Verify that 
the Virtual Machine Management service on the computer is running.
at New-Switch, <No file>: line 121
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 411
at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters) 
in C:\workspaces\stable 18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:line 36
at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean 
showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) in 
C:\workspaces\stable- 
18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 92
at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<Start>b__0() in 
C:\workspaces\stable- 
18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 74
at Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in 
C:\workspaces\stable- 
18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:line 59
```

I checked if Hyper-V is running on the computer.

I also did the following in powershell:

Ensure Windows Hyper-V featutes are enabled by running PowerShell cmdlet:

```
 Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All -Verbose
```

Ensure Windows Containers feature is enabled by running PowerShell cmdlet:

```
 Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers -All -Verbose
```

Ensure Hypervisor is set to auto start in the Boot Configuration Database (BCD) 
by running in elevated command prompt the command:

```
 bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto
```

( Found it on: [Failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255871/failed-to-start-the-virtual-machine-mobylinuxvm-because-one-of-the-hyper-v-com/48260575) )

But nothing helps.

I also reinstalled docker two times.

Comment: Have you tried running `MOFCOM %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof` in Command Prompt as administrator. Restart your machine afterwards. Found here: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/122307-fix-error-managing-hyper-v-server-2012-r2-from-windows-10

Comment: MOFCOM is not recognized, I tried

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo (MOFCOMP not mofcom): `MOFCOMP %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof`

Comment: I noticed just after I answered and tried it but it didn't help even after the reboot.

Comment: What is the Build number of Windows that you are using , it is like the most updated one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do make sure that the following three windows services are in running state

```
HV Host Service
Hyper-V Host Compute Service
Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management
```

Comment: Hyper-V Host Compute Service is not running. I can't run it ( ERROR 1053 ).

Comment: Can you try out the following  Step-By-Step: Enabling Hyper-V for use on Windows 10

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/09/08/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-10/

2. Most Hyper-v issues are relate to the network, please try to update the network driver to the latest version and see if it helps.

3. Please also refer to the following article and see if it helps.

A Workaround for Finding Missing Hyper-V Tools in Windows 10

https://www.petri.com/workaround-finding-missing-hyper-v-tools-windows-10

Comment: It works good with Windows containers but when I switch to linux containers it doesn't.

Comment: Under the docker desktop settings --> Advanced do you see the path of MobyLinux's Virtual Hard Disk , it could be like C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx , does it exists.

Comment: No there is nothing next to disk image location

Comment: When I manually go to that path it is empty, there is nothing under Virtual Hard Disks

Comment: You may need to reinstall Docker Desktop , in which case it will re-download the Virtual machine file

Comment: I did that twice... All of this is on the computer that they gave me at work. Is it possible that I doesn't work because I am trying it at home?

Comment: Make sure that when you run the installer you run it as admin and there is no disk space issue as well , since the file is more than 5 GB...

Comment: OK so try this first C:\>"Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\MobyLinux.ps1" -Create True , once done make sure that MobyLinuxVM file should exists in the shared location

Answer (score 0):

If Windows 10 you're referring to has an ancient edition (lower then anniversary, i.e. 1607) there is no chance in hell you can get it working. To check version of your OS run 'winver'. The problem with these editions is that they don't support nested virtualization Docker require.

Now, it's not clear WHERE are you running your VM. If it's VMWare on your PC it should be relatively easy to fix, but if it's Cloud, can be a different story. The thing is that in Azure, for instance, not all VMs support nested virtualization, so if you hastened to provision a VM, it might be a problem. If you want to get it right, use v3 VM types and up ([refer this article for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization)).

In my case 'HV Host Service' didn't work as well, but fortunately I was able to resize a VM to a proper tier (v3) and voila! Docker started right away.