# Installing Docker desktop on Windows Server 2016 getting "Failed to start virtual machine MobyLinuxVM because one of the Hyper-V components is not.."

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

[image: Windows 14393 is deprecated]I have Installed Docker desktop on Windows Server 2016 successfully but after installing it shows message. "Windows 14393 is deprecated".

Onwards when trying to start docker it prompts message "Failed to start virtual machine MobyLinuxVM because one of the Hyper-V components is not running"

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled hardware virtualization in the BIOS? It's off by default on many motherboards, and would prevent you from running docker.

Comment: yes  hardware virtualization is enabled

Comment: In that case, take a look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255871/failed-to-start-the-virtual-machine-mobylinuxvm-because-one-of-the-hyper-v-com)

Comment: Tried all options none of them works for me.

Comment: Finally got this in docker documentation:-
Docker Desktop is not supported on Windows Server 2016, instead you can use Docker Enterprise Basic Edition at no aditional cost.

Comment: If you figured it out, be sure to answer your own question in case other people have your same problem

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#hyper-v

Answer (score 1):

Docker Desktop is not supported on Windows Server 2016, instead you can use Docker Enterprise Basic Edition at no additional cost.
For Installation and setup follow below link.
https://hub.docker.com/editions/enterprise/docker-ee-server-windows

Comment: Also refer this link https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/windows/docker-ee/#update-docker-ee